# Aggregate functions on windows azure storage tables

Tags: group-by, aggregate-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a Windows Azure Storage table in which i am storing more than 1000k+ rows(entities).
I want to perform a few aggregate functions on the table, for example counting on 
a specific column for a specific condition, `average`, `total`, `min`, `max` and `group by` (as in normal SQL). How can I do that in windows Azure Storage tables?

Answer (score 7):

The only way is pretty much to pull down all your entities and run your aggregates on them in memory.

If you have to keep this information up to date I would store these aggregates in another place and update them every time a new entity is added. For instance the average is the `sum/count` so you can have a table item that stores the current sum and count and when you add a new entity also update the sum and count values.

Make sure to use optimistic concurrency so you can catch any race conditions etc. If your table entities share the same partition key then you can even do the operation on the same transaction.

Comment: Felix, thanks for the reply.
But, keeping all the entities in the local memory will slow down the processing plus the computational charges put on every update of the value in another place would cost an overhead. Can't afford such loss. As no. of trasnsactions increases, it directly increases my charges on cloud.
Looking for some other solution...

Comment: My two suggestions were seperate btw - you would either pull them all down and do the aggregates **or** keep a seperate store with grand totals etc - generally not both. The only other option is to use a RDMS store (Sql Server) which is designed for aggregate functions - but then (ironically perhaps) the cost will probably be more and it will not be as scalable.

Comment: this is basically for applying reporting on the Azure Storage Table datas. Anyway of achieving that?

Comment: The Azure Table Service is essentially just a key,value store. It has little in the way of convenience for aggregation and mathematical functions provided in some of the other Azure solutions like Azure SQL. Keeping a separate table that keeps track of denormalized counters might be your best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (as far as I am aware, as of June 2015) is that you can't.
See: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333963-add-support-for-aggregate-functions-like-count-su

**Update.**  The information linked to above applies to DocumentDB, not Table Storage (doh) (DocumentDB, like ATS, is also a NoSQL implementation).

That said (and RE the OPs question) pretty much the same state applies to Table Storage.  This suggestion: '[Add TableStorage LINQ query support for Select, Count and Contains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/415607-add-tablestorage-linq-query-support-for-select-co)' whilst not identical to what the OP is after would I guess be a move in the right general direction.  Unfortunately even though it seems they have started implementing these features there's still a lot of manual coding you'd have to do yourself.

> **Query Projection Feature**
>
> Projection refers to querying a subset of an entity or entities’
>   properties. This is analogous to selecting a subset of the
>   columns/properties of a certain table when querying in LINQ. It is a
>   mechanism that would allow an application to reduce the amount of data
>   returned by a query by specifying that only certain properties are
>   returned in the response. For more information, you can also refer to
>   Windows Azure Table: Query Entities, Windows Azure Table: Writing LINQ
>   Queries, WCF Data Services: Query Projections, and OData: Select
>   System Query Option ($select).

Thanks to @abatishchev for politely pointing out my inability to read.

Comment: You got confused between Azure Table Storage (ATS) and Azure DocumentDb (ADB), there are different frameworks, right?

Comment: No I didn't - I suggest you get your facts straight.  Azure Table Storage is a NoSQL implementation, not a SQL like one.  The closest I've seen to the OP's desired answer is people asking for it.  Ergo if you want to perform actions like 'average' then you need to write it yourself, as per Felix's answer.

Comment: I know ATS is NoSQL. But, still, OP asks about ATS and your link is about ADB.

Comment: Oh cripes you're absolutely correct, my mistake entirely, please accept my humblest appologies.  I found this link when searching for Table Storage info and didn't notice if referred to DocumentDB.  Have updated my answer.

Comment: The DocumentDb/Cosmos feature has now been completed: 
*completed  ·  AdminAzure Cosmos DB Team (Product Manager, Microsoft Azure) responded  ·  March 09, 2017*